# Weird System performance

Tags: 13.04, performance, cpu, system-monitor

I just freshly installed Ubuntu 13.04. My CPU seems to be going from 70 to 30 every 5 seconds or so. Same for the wireless. Weird stuff going on
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well, maybe there is a heavy process running behind as root, and you can't see it normally in System Monitor. Go to the processes tab, click 'View' in the menu and select 'All Processes' if you see one (it should be in one of the sub-folders), then check for the one that uses the highest CPU usage. One big possibility is the `oneconf` process, that eats up the CPU and RAM at some times. (You can't remove it if you want to use software center, it's a dependency)  
Besides that, Ubuntu is quite strange as it will magically update your software catalog in some times (that's why for your WIFI) just because it wants to check for system updates (and the CPU and RAM usage will be high). 
Hope that helps